# unzipping images into blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

in my app i need to do the following:
1. a zip file with images (jpgs only right now)and other stuff is uploaded into the BlobStore.
2. an app  engine backend should read the entries from the uploaded zip and save all images found inside to the BlobStore as stand alone files.

i successfully upload, unzip and save files @ blobstore, but the images seem to be broken.
when i download them from the BlobStore (simply blobstoreService.serve them) the images have wrong colors, or displayed partially, or broken in other ways. an attempt to use ImagesService also throws an exception. i checked the size of the images before they are zipped and the size of the files unzipped while written into the blobstore and they look the same. here is my code:

```
ZipInputStream zis = ...; 
ZipEntry entry;
while ((entry =zis.getNextEntry()) !=null)
{
    String fileName = entry.getName().toLowerCase();
    if(fileName.indexOf(".jpg") != -1 || fileName.indexOf(".jpeg") != -1)       
     {
        FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
        String mime = ctx.getMimeType(fileName);//getting mime from servlet context
        AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(mime, fileName);
        boolean lock = true;
        FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE];
        while(zis.read(buffer) >= 0)
        {
           ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
           writeChannel.write(bb);
        }
        writeChannel.closeFinally();
        BlobKey coverKey =  fileService.getBlobKey(file);
        ....
     }
}
```

thanks a lot for you time!

UPD: i found a work-around that works, but i still don't understand why the first solution failed.

```
            int read;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while((read = zis.read()) >= 0)
            {
                baos.write(read);
                if(baos.size() == BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE)
                {
                    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray());
                    writeChannel.write(bb);
                    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                }
            }
            if(baos.size() > 0)
            {
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray());
                writeChannel.write(bb);
            }
```

Comment: Try comparing the actual contents of the original image to the downloaded one - how do they differ?

Answer (score 1):

Because of zis.read(buffer) may not fill the entire buffer.

Use following instead

```
int len;
while((len = zis.read(buffer)) >= 0){
  ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, len);
  writeChannel.write(bb);
}
```

Hope this help